# Installing ccls through Homebrew outputs caveats messages related to libffi and llvm

Tags: c++, llvm, neovim, language-server-protocol, libffi

I'm trying to set my neovim C++ development environment, and want to use `ccls` as my coc language server.

When I installed `ccls` using `Homebrew`, it installs `libffi` and `llvm` as dependencies.
It seems like `ccls` is installed successfully, but it seems like I need to configure `PATH` variable,`LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`.

But I don't know what `libffi` and `llvm` are for, and they suggest different `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`, which is confusing.

Is it okay not to export any variables to use `ccls`? Or, which version should I export in my `~/.zshrc`?

Below is my console output for `brew install ccls`.

```
❯ brew install ccls
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libffi-3.3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/llvm-11.0.0_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/c8e30903a9a4f695780e1eeeaa2cf4d5a95141a1cac98ab1bbc811817cde39ca?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ccls-0.20201219.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/934fb8fd594d6e7adbfa14b5608f1de14309db34f2cf61a0cb572bdc772b2aa3?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing dependencies for ccls: libffi and llvm
==> Installing ccls dependency: libffi
==> Pouring libffi-3.3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
libffi is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libffi/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3: 17 files, 540.2KB
==> Installing ccls dependency: llvm
==> Pouring llvm-11.0.0_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/11.0.0_1: 8,922 files, 1.4GB
==> Installing ccls
==> Pouring ccls-0.20201219.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ccls/0.20201219: 5 files, 1.5MB
==> Caveats
==> libffi
libffi is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libffi/include"

==> llvm
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libffi` is only a library. And `llvm` is a *compiler infrastructure*.
And `libc++` is the C++ standard library of the *LLVM Project*. You can use the *LLVM* library or the GNU (`libstdc++`) one. It depends on your software project (or your personal preferences) what library you use.

Since macOS does already deliver a `llvm` installation you can *optionally* switch to the one installed as dependency by *brew* – which is not required.

The `LDFLAGS` environment variable does hold additional flags which is passed by your compiler (`gcc/g++` or `clang/clang++`) to the linker, i.e. adding the path where the linker can find the library object files which are then, if required/used, linked against your binary.

And `CPPFLAGS` does the same, but this time the flags are targeting the compiler directly, i.e. adding an additional search path for the header files of the library.

And in your case you don't have to export any (additional) variables from your `.zshrc`, `ccls` will work fine for you without defining those variables.

Comment: What an explanation! Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: If it worked for you, please do not forget to mark it as answer :D